# Regex expression for URLs to get elements before a certain pattern

Tags: regex

I have URLs that look something like: `https://something/something/us/en/something`. I want to extract the elements `us` before `en`. I am using regex for this.

So far I have gotten close to getting this `\us\` using `'\/[a-z]{2}[\/en]'` . How to get the two letters before `en` using regex?

Comment: Like this perhaps `https?:\\\\\S+?\\([a-z]{2})\\en\b` https://regex101.com/r/zW7q49/1 Should the ``\`` be ``/`` in the url?

Comment: `[A-Za-z]+(?=[\\\/]en[\\\/])`

Answer (score 1):

You specified backslashes in the url, and forward slashes in your regex. Assuming forward slashes for url and regex, you can define a match regex, or a replace regex:

```js
const url = 'https://something/something/us/en/something';
const regex1 = /\b[a-z]{2}(?=\/en\/)/;
const regex2 = /^.*\/([a-z]{2})\/en\/.*$/;
console .log('regex1 match: ' + url.match(regex1));
console .log('regex2 replace: ' + url.replace(regex2, '$1'));
```

Output:

```
regex1 match: us
regex2 replace: us
```

Explanation of regex1 for match:

- `\b[a-z]{2}` - expect two chars after a word boundary
- `(?=\/en\/)` - followed by a positive lookahead for `/en/`

Explanation of regex2 for replace:

- `^.*` ... `.*$` - scan from very start to very end (anchor on both sides)
- `\/` - within this, expect `/`
- `([a-z]{2})` - then capture two lowercase chars
- `\/en\/` - then expect `/en/`
- the replace `'$1'` uses only the captured group

Answer (score 0):

First, your URL is flawed, you have the wrong slashes.

You were very close, you just needed to put the capture parentheses around the thing you wanted to actually "get"

```
\/([a-z]{2})\/en\/
```

https://regex101.com/r/w1x7eY/1

However, this will only work if you know 100% sure that the thing *before* the `/en/` bit will always be 2 letters.

If you wanted to let it capture the path part before, try this.

```
\/([^\/]*)\/en\/
```

https://regex101.com/r/0GJaq9/1